# Spring cxf client configuration

Tags: web-services, spring, cxf

I'm creating a cxf web service client using Spring 3.0, it works good, but i want to improve the configuration. The client is declared as follows:

```
 <jaxws:client id="myClient"
          serviceClass="package.myClass"
          address="http://localhost:8181/services/MyEndpoint?wsdl" />
```

I need to inject the **address** property, i mean, it is hardcoded in the xml file, but i want to declare it into a properties file. how can i do that? that address can change.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use a property placeholder.  See [4.8.2.1 the PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-placeholderconfigurer)

Comment: thanks it worked!. i tried something similar, i've used a: <util:properties id="config" location="classpath:/META-INF/config.properties"/> but it didn't inject the value.